# $f(x)=\cos(ax+b)$ find $f'(x)$ , $f''(x)$, $f'''(x)$, $f''''(x)$ and give a general form for $f^{(n)}( x)$ where there s cosinus

Tags: derivatives

I found
\begin{align*}
f'(x)&=-a\cos(\pi/2-ax-b) \\
f''(x)&= a^2 \cos(ax+b) \\
f'''(x)&=-a^3 \cos(\pi/2-ax-b) \\
f''''(x) &= a^4 \cos(ax+b) \\
f^{(n)} (x)&= (-1)^n a^n \cos(\dotsb +((-1)^n))(ax+b)
\end{align*}
I son t know what about the $\pi/2$ please help thanks

Comment: You made a mistake at $f''(x)$, there's an extra minus. You then carried this mistake all the way.

Comment: Hi, $f'(x)=-asin(ax+b)=acos(ax+b+\frac{\pi}2)$